# How to write at a specific address past end of file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, file-io, stl, fstream

I am working with an `fstream` object, and I was wondering how is it possible to write something past the end of file, without having to manually fill the space in-between the eof and the desired location with zeroes?

Example :

```
fstream someFile;
someFile.open("foo.dat", ios :: out | ios :: trunc | ios :: binary); // file is created, and empty
someFile.seekp(100, ios :: beg); // expecting 100 zeroes to be written in file, but nothing happens
someFile.write("yodelay-hee-hoo", 15); // file is still empty, does not work
```

I've been searching on the issue for about an hour, but I can't find anything much relevant. The only thing I came across is someone that said using `.seekp` with `ios :: end` is supposed to fill the gap with zeroes, but I tried and it didn't work for me.

If it helps, I'm on VS2010, native compiling. Thanks a bunch if you can provide a tip.

Comment: You say you want to use `ios::end` but your code says `ios::beg`

Comment: So, seekp probably sets stream to error state. What is the error?

Comment: Why don't you want to write those zeros yourself ? It would likely be as efficient and would result in a far more explicit code. Or am I missing something ?

Comment: *but it doesn't work for me* - what does that mean? Does it produce an error? Don't you want to use it?

Comment: @KarthikT & @Björn: for my purposes, using `ios::beg` is much easier, but I mean that I did try with `ios::end` and it didn't work.
@hyde: Right after the `seekp` the error state is 7, which matches `eofbit | failbit | badbit`

Comment: @ereOn: well, I thought it would just be simpler if `seekp` handled it directly, because I have multiple `seekp`'s across my code, instead of copy 'n pasting a filler code before every call.

Comment: @AgentRev: I don't know if this behavior is guaranteed, but if it is then sure, doing so is probably not necessary. If it is not, making a wrapper function might solve the problem transparently.

Comment: @AgentRev Why don't you simply write your own class inheriting from (or containing) fstream with apropriate filler code before seekp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short:** `.seekp()` fails if end-of-file was previously reached with `.seekg()`, thus requiring a call to `.clear()` beforehand.

---

**Long:**

I found that my write operations failed because I first sought a position past the end-of-file with `.seekg()`, and verified if there was data at that location, by first checking if `.eof()` returned false and then looking for a non-null character with `.peek()`.

The thing is, even if `.seekg()` reaches the end-of-file, `.eof()` seems to always return false until any read/peek/get operation is attempted, and `.peek()` returns a non-null value (-1) for any position past the end-of-file.

Therefore, the solution was to check for a non-null character **before** checking if end-of-file was reached, **and** if past end-of-file, calling `.clear()` before `.seekp()`, and it solved everything.